# How to toggle between 2 icons

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have to toggle between two icons based on some criteria. How do I do this in jQuery?

```
<a href='' id="home" onclick="myfunction(this)" data-toggle="toggle">
    <span class="fa fa-train"></span>
</a>
```

```js
myfunction($this) {
    // ...

    if ($($this).hasClass("fa fa-train")) {
        $($this).removeClass("fa fa-train");
        $($this).addClass("fa fa-car");
    }
    else {
        $($this).addClass("fa fa-car");
        $($this).addClass("fa fa-train");
    }

    // ...
}
```

Comment: you sure you need to do $($this). and not directly $this. ?

Comment: Are you double-wrapping your jQuery objects? In theory `$this` should already be a jQuery object due to its naming convention, so shouldn't need `$()` around it again.

Comment: No, the html event-handler passes simply `this` to the function. Yes, it's a strange naming method, but - unless I'm missing something silly - it's clearly *not* a jQuery object passed to the named function. "*…based on some criteria*" - based on what criteria? Incidentally, you have no closing quote for your `<a>` element's `href` attribute-value.

Answer (score 1):

clicked anchor element do not have class added, its child span does :

```
function myfunction($this) {
  $($this).find('span').toggleClass('fa-train fa-car');
}
```

Comment: or just `$this.toggleClass('fa-train fa-car')`

Answer (score 0):

Do something like this

```
 $('a#home').on('click', function(){
   var childSpan = $(this).find('span');
   if(childSpan.hasClass('fa-train')){
     childSpan.removeClass('fa-train');
     childSpan.addClass('fa-car');
   }
   else if(childSpan.hasClass('fa-car')){
    childSpan.removeClass('fa-car');
    childSpan.addClass('fa-train');
   }});
```

Answer (score 0):

you are using this which will check the a tag if has class . while you should check in the span next to a tag .you should use like this

```
myfunction($this) {
    // ...

    if ($($this).next('span').hasClass("fa fa-train")) {
        $($this).next('span').removeClass("fa fa-train");
        $($this).next('span').addClass("fa fa-car");
    }
    else {
        $($this).next('span').addClass("fa fa-car");
        $($this).next('span').addClass("fa fa-train");
    }

    // ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

With a condition in one line:

```
$($this)
  .addClass((condition=(Math.random() > .5)) ? 'fa-car' : 'fa-train')
  .removeClass(condition ? 'fa-train': 'fa-car')
```

*Note: This will not work if you `"use strict"` and of course your code will be less readable.*

Answer (score 0):

Thanks everyone, yes i had to search for 'span' and add toggle class. hasClass is also good way to check beforehand that the class exist or not.

Answer (score 0):

This is a concept that I came with which is a bit logical. Instead of using complicated language, what this does is it hides the add button and makes a times button while showing the message that was hidden. It is fairly simple JQuery.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#addCross").click(function() {
    document.getElementById("addCross").style.display = "none";
    document.getElementById("addAdd").style.display = "inline-block";
    document.getElementById("hello").style.display = "block";
  });
  $("#addAdd").click(function() {
    document.getElementById("addCross").style.display = "inline-block";
    document.getElementById("addAdd").style.display = "none";
    document.getElementById("hello").style.display = "none";
  });
});
```

```css
/* 
   Unoptional CSS 
   Just to make the buttons look better in the snippet. 
*/

button {
  background: transparent;
  border: none;
}

button:focus {
  outline: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/9b271ce18a.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<div>
  <label>Press the Button: </label>
  <button id="addCross"><i class="fas fa-plus"></i>
  <button id="addAdd" style="display: none;"><i class="fas fa-times"></i></button>
  <div style="display: none;" id="hello">
    <p>Hello. I was hidden by the Magic of JQuery.</p>

    <label>This design also makes a cool rotating add sign if you look closely. Ha Ha!!</label>
  </div>
```